# Turning a for loop to recursive method for prime numbers

Tags: java

I need to convert the code below to a recursive method without using global variables and using only one parameter.I  Searched the topics already there is no code with one parameter and doesnt use the global variables.

```
public boolean isPrime(int x){
 for(int i=2;i<x;i++)
  if(x%i==0) return false ;
 return true; 
}
```

Comment: you cannot do it. you will need one more parameter. Bad question.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by making this recursive? That may make it easier to help you. Especially since the given method appears to perform its job fine as is

Comment: I know its a stupid question but it come up in one of my university exams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my schoolmates' topic accually recieve a solution here it is if you interested its quite brilliant
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660562/finding-prime-numbers-recursively-with-using-only-one-parameter?noredirect=1#comment59001671_35660562

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting problem.
If you can use **java 8**, you can solve the problem as followed (note that the case `isPrime(2)` needs to be checked with an additional if condition):

```
package test;

import java.util.function.Function;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPrime(13));
    }

    private static Function<Integer, Boolean> fun;

    public static boolean isPrime(int x) {
        fun = i -> {
            if (i > 2) return (x%i != 0) && fun.apply(i-1);
            else return (x%i != 0);
        };
        return fun.apply(x-1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as for your requirements:

- Without using global variables.
- Using only one parameter.

And, based on:

> it come up in one of my university exams

There a couple of aspects to take into account:

- If you pass an **instance of a Class** you are passing only one variable, and as **Classes** can have multiple **variables** inside...
- They do not state if you can call multiple functions inside, so, again, this is a hint or clue, of what can you do. So, two solutions for you:

> **Solution 1 (Using Classes)**

```
class RecursVar {
    int x;
    int i = 2;

    RecursVar(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

public boolean isPrimeRecurs(int x){
    return isPrime(new RecursVar(x));
}

boolean isPrime(RecursVar recursVar) {
    if(recursVar.x % recursVar.i == 0) 
        return false;
    if (++recursVar.i >= recursVar.x)
        return true;

    return isPrime(recursVar);
}
```

> **Solution 2 (Cleaner approach without using Classes but based in that the function that can have only one parameter is `isPrime` )**

```
boolean isPrime(int x) {
    return checkForPrime(x, 2);
}

boolean checkForPrime(int x, int i) {
    if (i >= x) return true;
    if (x % i == 0) return false;

    return checkForPrime(x, ++i);
}
```

Again, this solutions are based on that many exams require a little creativity and maybe that was the aim of this case.

> This cases should not be used in production, they are **slow** and
>   prune to make honor to this site (**StackOverFlow**) with a sweet
>   `java.lang.StackOverflowError`